# How do I make eval register integers such as 05 and 04 as valid?

Tags: python, tkinter, eval, calculator

I'm making a GUI calculator using tkinter and have run into a problem I can't seem to fix.  Part of the requirements of the program is that the calculator works with input such as "02+04" which would return "6".  When I try and enter this calculation into the `Entry` field I get the error

> SyntaxError: invalid token

I've tried looking up how to get around and/or troubleshoot this error but have had no luck so far. Any help on how to make this work would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to do this with `eval` in the first place? `eval` evaluates arbitrary Python code. It doesn't evaluate things that aren't Python code, while at the same time it does evaluate things that are Python code that you didn't want evaluated like `__import__('sys').exit()`. If you design an expression language that's similar to, but not the same as, a subset of Python, you need to write a parser and interpreter for that language, or at least a parser and a translater-to-Python for that language.

Comment: Hi, the eval function in my program is unable to evaluate any python code that isn't supposed to be evaluated as it is unable to be entered into the entry field, so this is not a problem.  I was told to construct the program by making use of eval for the operations, which is why I'm trying to do it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: eval is unsafe.

Comment: If you were told to use `eval`, and you were also told you have to handle inputs that aren’t valid Python inputs, then either this is a really unfair assignment, or they’re expecting you to write a translator from your language to Python expressions. There’s really no way around that. Maybe they want you to write a really hacky simple translator, but they want you to write a translator. Either that, or they just don’t know wha they’re talking about and gave you an unfair assignment.

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf how is eval unsafe when the function isn't able to evaluate anything that I don't want to be evaluated? I've put in place the required input validation checks so that this isn't a problem.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for your help! Could you explain what that code actually does? It's a high school teacher so most definitely incompetent.

Comment: @Devin I'll repost it as an answer after cleanup.

Comment: Sweet as thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `eval` is frowned upon as pointed out in the comments and numerous places on the web. Even if input is sanitized, it's a design crutch.

Having said that, it sounds like you're obligated to do it this way, so you may use this regex to replace leading zeros on numbers in the expression you plan to `eval`:

```
self.answer = eval(re.sub(r"((?<=^)|(?<=[^\.\d]))0+(\d+)", r"\1\2", self.equation.get()))
```

Breakdown of the regex:

```
(                             # begin capturing group \1
 (?<=^)                       # positive lookbehind to beginning of line
       |                      # OR
        (?<=[^\.\d])          # positive lookbehind to non-digit, non-period character
                    )         # end capturing group \1
                     0+       # literal 0 one or more times
                       (\d+)  # one or more digits (capturing group \2)
```

Don't forget to `import re` at the top of your script.

Comment: Hey man, thanks heaps for your help! Just have a quick question.  I tried doing what this answer outlines, but it makes it so that input such as 0.02+1 returns 1.2 instead of 1.02.  Is there any way to fix this?  E.g don't remove a leading zero after the decimal point?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Sorry I know this was quite a while ago, but I have a few quick questions if that's okay @ggorlen.  While researching regular expressions, I came across the following expression: result = re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0).  In the example that you gave to help me out, where is the "repl" replacement that the leading zeroes get replaced with if matched?  Also, what do 'Group 1' and 'Group 2' represent?  Does Group 2 represent a pattern where the leading zeroes are before digits, and Group 1 the beginning or a non-digit, non-period character?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Also, what is the r"\1\2" used for? Just trying to get a better grasp on the regex :)